# Create temp table with start and end index of a special char

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have string with special char as '|'

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = Column1,True,3|Column2,True,2|Column3,True,6;

DECLARE @columns AS TABLE(Clm VARCHAR(50));
```

Requirement: create a temp table as below from the above string

```
Column1
Column2
Column3
```

My approach:

```
WITH columns AS 
(
    SELECT
        CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS idx1, 
        CHARINDEX('|', @string) idx2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        idx2 + 1, CHARINDEX('|', @string, idx2 + 1)
    FROM
        columns  
    WHERE 
        idx2 > 0
)
INSERT INTO @column
    SELECT
        LEFT(SUBSTRING(@string, idx1, COALESCE(NULLIF(idx2, 0), LEN(@string) + 1) - idx1,
                       CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING(@string, idx1, COALESCE(NULLIF(idx2,0), LEN(@string) + 1) - idx1)) - 1) AS value
    FROM 
        columns;
```

I am able to achieve what is needed but seeing performance issue. Taking 30 sec in prod.

Please help me with better ways.

Comment: MySQL or  (MS) sql-server? Please remove unrelated tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to do two splits, but only one is actually necessary, as the second split only needs the first value.

**So we can split on `|`, then search for the first `,`**

```sql
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Column1,True,3|Column2,True,2|Column3,True,6';

DECLARE @columns AS TABLE(Clm VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @column (Clm)
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN v1.comma > 0
          THEN LEFT(split.[value], v1.comma - 1)
          ELSE split.[value]
        END
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, '|') split
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(',', split.[value]) ) ) v1(comma);
```

You need at least SQL Server 2017 to be able to use `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the version. I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Time to upgrade?